# How to recognise duplicates through textfield

Tags: java, sql, duplicates, detect

im using netbeans to program my jukebox simulator however im having trouble with writing a code for detecting duplicate input (Textfield).

for e.g. im using a line of code where if the user inputs say 11 an error message comes up as my database holds track numbers 1-10, this is done through the following code,

`if (name == null) {
playcount.setText("no such track number");
}`

(name is a String that stores the song name after the user has inputted a number, my program looks up the number from my SQL server database and returns the song name which is stored in name)

and also when the user presses the reset button the database in SQL server deleted the content of the my Playlist Table

so basically i want to be able to detect if the user has inputted say for example "2" twice, but also once the database has been reset the user should be able to input track "2" again. thanks in advance

Comment: Based on what I understood from what you wrote, you are storing user's selections on a different table. You can query that table to see whether or not that song is there already. The question is why are you resetting the my Playlist Table every time someone hits reset? What if there are more than one users in the system?

Comment: its not suppose to be a public jukebox, its mento simulate windows media player (sort of), its suppose to be separate, ill also make improvements where the user can store upto 3 separate playlists later on.

Comment: Do what @jail has said and when the user hits reset, you just delete the content of the selection table.